# SAS and Principal Components Analysis

Tags: pca, sas

I'm new to SAS coding from SPSS point and click. I don't currently have SPSS, so SAS is my only option.

My question is: how do I get the percent variance explained and cumulative variance explained following varimax rotation?? I get the total that I would get under 
'Rotation Sums of Square Loadings' but not the % variance or cumulative %.

Example SAS code below:

```
PROC FACTOR DATA=survey
METHOD=PRIN
PRIORS=ONE
NFACT=2
MINEIGEN=1
SCREE
ROTATE=VARIMAX
FLAG=.32
OUT=ex4comp4;
VAR pn1 pn2 pn3 pn4 pn5 pn6 pn7 pn8 pn9 pn10 pn11 pn12 pn13 pn14 pn15 pn16 pn17 pn18 pn19 pn20;
RUN;
```

Essentially I want to know what % variance each factor explains but all I get is the Total.

So frustrated and confused!

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or solutions
KWAK

Comment: How do you get from 'I don't have SPSS' to 'SAS is my only option'?

Comment: Hi Glen, what I meant is that I have SAS on my computer right now and I am trying to do the work right now. Thanks.

Comment: I can't check right now (with SPSS but no SAS now, ironically), but the percentages you want come as default (e.g. [1](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_factor_sect004.htm), [2](http://www.yorku.ca/pek/index_files/quickstart/FactorQuickStart.pdf)). My guess is your nfact and mineigen statements might have suppressed them. Start from a simpler command and see if that's true.

Comment: I typed my answer while you were typing your comment. :-). One further note, I think the MINEIGEN and NFACTORS statements are sort of either/or, NFACTORS insists on 2 factors while MINEIGEN says keep only those with eigenvalue over 1.

Comment: Hmm, even with the following basic code i still don't get what I'm looking for.  PROC FACTOR DATA=survey
NFACT=2
ROTATE=VARIMAX;
VAR pn1 pn2 pn3 pn4 pn5 pn6 pn7 pn8 pn9 pn10 pn11 pn12 pn13 pn14 pn15 pn16 pn17 pn18 pn19 pn20;
RUN;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of the default output; see the table called "Eigenvalues of the correlation matrix" and look in the two columns on the right.

EDIT with additional info:

A bit of googling found [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/140497) which shows how to get this by using PROC PRINCOMP.

Comment: Thank you Peter - that's what I was expecting from my results, but I don't seem to get that output. I must be missing something obvious here. When I reduce the number of factors to 2 and run the varimax rotation I receive the initial (non-rotated) table with eigenvalues and the two columns on the right. However, I do not received a second similar table following the rotated solution. My output shows the correct total (e.g. 4.886) but not the % var or cumulative %. (Correct is known because I am trying to replicate some SPSS results done previously)

Comment: Hang on! I can't figure out how to get it to come up, BUT am i correct in saying that if my total after rotation is 4.886 and I have 20 items then my percent variance is 4.886/20*100!!!

Comment: My apologies Peter- the total variance remains the same but the % variance explained by each factor may change. Now I understand how to calculate it, I have to go and figure out why so I understand it properly. Thank you for your time and efforts!